# pygal charts not displaying tooltips in Jupyter / IPython notebook

Tags: python, svg, ipython, jupyter-notebook, pygal

After much research, I finally managed to get tooltips working in [pygal](http://www.pygal.org/) thus:

```
Config = pygal.Config()
Config.js = ['http://kozea.github.io/pygal.js/2.0.x/pygal-tooltips.js']
bar_chart = pygal.Bar(Config)                                      # Then create a bar graph object
bar_chart.add('Fibonacci', [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55])  # Add some values
bar_chart.render_to_file('bar_chart.svg', force_uri_protocol='https')
```

In the produced .svg, tooltips are now working nicely, but *only when the file is opened in a browser*.

When the chart is displayed directly in Jupyter (either with `IPython.core.display.SVG(filename="bar_chart.svg")` or simply `bar_chart`), the tooltips and styling are not present.

Is this a known limitation? Or can it be achieved?

Comment: did you solve your issue ? I have the same here (ie : no tooltip for pygal + jupyter)

Answer (score 8):

My workaround involved setting up the HTML with the necessary javascript and chart svg like so:

```
import pygal
from IPython.display import display, HTML

base_html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://kozea.github.com/pygal.js/javascripts/svg.jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://kozea.github.io/pygal.js/2.0.x/pygal-tooltips.min.js""></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <figure>
      {rendered_chart}
    </figure>
  </body>
</html>
"""

def galplot(chart):
    rendered_chart = chart.render(is_unicode=True)
    plot_html = base_html.format(rendered_chart=rendered_chart)
    display(HTML(plot_html))

bar_chart = pygal.StackedBar()
bar_chart.add('Bars', [1,2,3,4,5])

galplot(bar_chart)
```

Not the prettiest solution, but it works

Answer (score 1):

Found [this](http://ino.pm/blog/ipython-pygal/) on the Google search that led me to this question. If you read the pygal documentation or look at an example SVG it generates, you'll see it includes pygal.js, which is missing in your notebook.